# I keep getting a type error got str instead of int

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pickle
usernames_passwords = open("username_password.pck", "wb")
customer_login = []
pickle.dump(customer_login, usernames_passwords, "wb")
usernames_passwords.close()
```

I'm trying to dump a list of usernames and passwords into a pickle file, and I keep getting a type error. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/andy/PycharmProjects/python/venv/scratch.py", line 4, in <module>
    pickle.dump(customer_login, usernames_passwords, "wb")
    TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Isn't `protocol` (the third argument to `pickle.dump`) supposed to be an int? You're passing `"wb"`.

Comment: the third argument is suppose to be a dump of the list which contains strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `pickle` docs:

> The optional protocol argument, an integer, tells the pickler to use the given protocol; supported protocols are 0 to HIGHEST_PROTOCOL. If not specified, the default is DEFAULT_PROTOCOL. If a negative number is specified, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL is selected.

So, your third argument is using the format you'd use to open a file, but `pickle` works differently and expects an `int`. See the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler).